# How do you merge an .ico file with the compiled .exe file?

Tags: c#, icons

how do you merge an .ico file with the compiled
.exe file?

without the .ico file, the exe file will crash upon booting... 
I've already added the ico file in the project properties

thanks in advance

Comment: Are you using it as an embedded resource?  Are you using the form properties?

Answer (score 5):

You need add the file as part of the solution either as content or embedded resource within the properties of the .ico file in your project solution.

Answer (score 1):

- Right-click your project, Add,  Existing item.
- Navigate to your .ico and select it.
- Select the main window of your project.
- Under properties (of the window) find icon and expand the ellipsis.
- Click the icon you added to your project.

Answer (score 0):

If they are already added to project properties, you can access them using the code.

```
Properties.Resources.<name of icon resource>
```

I hope this is accurate, as I'm writing this on my phone :)